# ¿Cómo crear un marcador responsive horizontalmente usando bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, css3, responsive

Indagando un por la web, pude estructurar el siguiente código responsive, el único problema es que el estilo es desordenado, verticalmente:

```css
.upcoming-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 93px 0 98px;
}

.upcoming-section .container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.upcoming-section h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.upcoming-section h4 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 14px 0 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.upcoming-section span.date {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.upcoming-section span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.upcoming-section .vs {
  color: #fbc02d;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <div class="upcoming-section">
  <div class="container">
   <h2>Upcoming Match</h2>
   <div id="upcoming" class="rs-carousel owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/media/sports/logos/9toerdOg8xW4CRhDaZxsyw_96x96.png" alt="">
       <h4>Trirsal</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <span class="date">JUNE 16, 17:00</span>
      <span class="vs">VS</span>
      <span>Central Olympic Stadium</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/media/sports/logos/9toerdOg8xW4CRhDaZxsyw_96x96.png" alt="">
      <h4>Kapa Club</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Como había redactado el pequeño defecto en el diseño, cuando cambio el tamaño de la ventana del navegador, al hacer responsive el diseño se desordena de manera verticalmente.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el diseño sea adaptable a cualquier dispositivo móvil conservando un responsive horizontalmente? Sin que exista algún desorden vertical o otro defecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya tienes el diseño, solo falto un pequeño detalle para que se conserve el mismo estilo horizontal, para ello debes reemplazar esto: `col-xs-12` por `col-xs-4`

Puedes mirar un poco más la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/) con algunos ejemplos muy prácticos.

- [sistema de filas y colummnas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```css
.upcoming-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 93px 0 98px;
}

.upcoming-section .container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.upcoming-section h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.upcoming-section h4 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 14px 0 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.upcoming-section span.date {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.upcoming-section span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.upcoming-section .vs {
  color: #fbc02d;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <div class="upcoming-section">
  <div class="container">
   <h2>Upcoming Match</h2>
   <div id="upcoming" class="rs-carousel owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/media/sports/logos/9toerdOg8xW4CRhDaZxsyw_96x96.png" alt="">
       <h4>Trirsal</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <span class="date">JUNE 16, 17:00</span>
      <span class="vs">VS</span>
      <span>Central Olympic Stadium</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/media/sports/logos/9toerdOg8xW4CRhDaZxsyw_96x96.png" alt="">
      <h4>Kapa Club</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo :)

Answer (score 1):

En efecto veo que es mucho el código para lo que realmente hace, he simplificado esto para que te des una idea que no se requiere tanto código para lograr algo similar a lo que pretendes. Lo hice muy sencillo, espero que te sirva de guía para lo que intentas realizar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
   @media screen and (max-width: 400px){
   .sp{
    font-size:12px;
   }
   
   .logo{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
   }
   
   } 
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12"> 
    <div class="text-center">
                   <span class="sp">Francia</span>
     <img class="img-responsive logo" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/media/sports/logos/z3JEQB3coEAGLCJBEUzQ2A_96x96.png" alt="">
     <span class="sp">2</span>
     <span>VS</span>
     <span class="sp">1</span>
     <img class="img-responsive logo" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/media/sports/logos/9toerdOg8xW4CRhDaZxsyw_96x96.png" alt="">
     <span class="sp">Croacia</span>
                </div>
    <div class="text-center">
     <span class="sp"> <input type="checkbox"> Mañana - 15 Julio 2018 - 10:00AM </span> <br>
     <span class="sp">Estadio - Olímpico Luzhnikí</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="text-center">
     <a href="" target="_blank"><span class="moto-widget-button-label sp">Ver detalles</span></a>
    </div>    
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo el código que has dado no se adapta en mi código, no se visualiza igual como se observa aquí, sin embargo el nuevo código proporcionado en mi edición de mi pregunta, ese código si se adapta a mi código sin ningún error, el único problema es que se desordena de manera vertical al hacer responsive, yo deseo que continué de manera horizontalmente el responsive.